# DB in MySQL migrate to Oracle DB

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I need to migrate some tables in mysql db to oracle db.

Do you now any tutorial to learn about this migration?

Thanks

Comment: If you've accepted it, why not vote it up as well?

Comment: Wait a little : you will get a new sticker :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect to the MySQL instance from Oracle using Oracle's database link - [this link](http://www.pythian.com/news/1554/how-to-access-mysql-from-oracle-with-odbc-and-sql/) details making the connection from Oracle to MySQL.

Bearing in mind that the MySQL account you use to create the connection will determine access to MySQL data, once the link is created you can work within Oracle to select data from the MySQL tables into the Oracle tables without a need for scripts and such.

Answer (score 3):

Find an ETL tool like Informatica or SSIS to help you.  [Oracle's Migration Workbench](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/migration/workbench/index.html) might be the perfect choice, since you're already using Oracle.